# Jenkins Username and Password Error (E-mail Notification)

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

I'm trying to configure E-mail notifications in Jenkins. 
But it is showing the following error...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGA7x.jpg)

I tried it with Admin account Then with my own gmil account & passd . I also created a new user in Jenkins & tried with its Uname & Passwd though not able to solve.

error::

> Failed to send out e-mail
>
> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and
>   Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 
>   https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials x11sm87366623pfe.72
>   - gsmtp
>
> at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:809)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:752)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:669)
>     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)     at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)  at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)    at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
>   hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:585)    at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:77)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:99)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>     at
>   hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
>     at
>   hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
>     at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
>     at
>   winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 2):

Check if your Gmail account can use less secure apps: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Finally I recommend you to use the [Extended E-mail notification](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin in jenkins, it allows more options than the basic E-mail notification plugin.